# RHEL 5.1 install error

Tags: linux, usb, drivers

Facing the error "The Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server CD was not found in any of your CDROM drivers"

The following are the questions we seek response for:

1. The question might be a lengthy one, please bear with me. We were trying to install RHEL 5 in a Supermicro hardware which does not have USB 2.0 ports and has only USB 3.0 ports (4 ports), an initial phase of attempt as the installation proceeds we faced the error "Unable to download kickstart file [path cdrom:/ks/ks.cfg]] and from this point the Keyboard (usb 2.0) nor the scsi dvd RW driver where getting detected. We included xHCI driver in vmlinuz and now the Keyboard (usb 2.0) is functional but we are facing the error with cdrom "The Red Hat Enterprise Linux Server CD was not found in any of your CDROM drivers".
2. In our iso, There is an ELF file labelled "loader" which loads certain ko's listed in the initrd image, the source file of which we do not have. Any pointers on where we could possibly get the source file from.

Debugs steps tried so far:

We are using a custom iso build on RHEL 5.1 .

Keep xHCI driver as part of initrd.img -  In our iso, There is a ELF file labelled "loader" which loads certain ko's listed in the initrd image , the source file of which we do not have. Since we do not have source file we cannot generate or edit the ELF file "loader" to load the additional driver we added i.e. xhci-hcd.ko.Hence decided to add the xHCI driver as part of vmlinuz and we could succeed with loading the driver and keyboard(usb 2.0) is functional.

Ensure usb-storage.ko is loaded.

Remove the DVD once the error is hit and re-insert the DVD back again and hit "Ok" - No success

Once the error is hit remove the hardware drive and re-insert say after ~30 seconds.- No success

Our isolinux.cfg file:
serial 0 9600
default auto
prompt 1
timeout 600
display boot.msg
F1 boot.msg
F2 aconfigs.msg
F3 options.msg

label auto
  kernel vmlinuz
  append initrd=initrd.img ks=cdrom:/ks/ks.cfg ks_zerombr

Command used to generate the iso:
    mkisofs -o Custom.iso -b isolinux/isolinux.bin -c isolinux/boot.cat -no-emul-boot -boot-load-size 4 -boot-info-table -quiet -r -J -V "FullInstallation" -m .CC -m .ACME .

Also tried modifying isolinux.cfg file as  : - No success

```
append initrd=initrd.img inst.stage2=hd:LABEL=FullInstallation ks=hd:LABEL=FullInstallation:/ks/ks.cfg
```

Other info:

We are using the DVD-RW CD on which the bootable iso has been burnt and it is being read using SCSI DVD-RW hardware drive.

The kernel we use is 2.6.32-27.basic , Due to certain constrains in the project we cannot upgrade the kernel.

Comment: Is installing in a VM an alternative for this use case?

Comment: Hi Mikael H, appreciate your response, we wouldn't be able to go with the alternative of installing in VM, as for this use case the attempt is being made on a physical server/hardware the same for which the resolution is being sought.